# Alternative to car lm.beta for standardizing regression coefficients?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I'm trying to standardize regression coefficients for a linear regression model which has interaction terms. Currently, I'm using `lm.beta` from the `car` package, but the help file states:

> Warning: This function does not produce 'correct' standardized
>   coefficients when interaction terms are present

Since my regression has interaction terms, this is worrying. Is there an alternative to `car`'s `lm.beta` which standardizes regression coefficients and works with regression models with interactions?

Comment: `?arm::standardize` use google

Comment: Thanks...and for the record, I did use google before posting here. No need to be harsh about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scale` function to scale your data before passing it to `lm`.  This does not require any extra packages and gives the standardized regression.  Here is a simple example:

```
iris2 <- iris
iris2[ ,c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width')] <- scale(iris2[ ,c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width')])
fit <- lm( Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=iris2)
```